# Why is my field not updated in Mvc with EditorFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Any help to understand why my field isn't updated in Mvc and how to properly fix this?

This is my controller:

```
public class RestaurantController : Controller
{
        static List<RestaurantModel> rr = new List<RestaurantModel>()
        {
            new RestaurantModel() { Id = 1, Name = "Kebabs", Location = "TX" },
            new RestaurantModel() { Id = 2, Name = "Flying Donoughts", Location = "NY" }
        };
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           var model = from r in rr
                orderby r.Name
                select r;
            return View(model);
        }
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var rev = rr.Single(r => r.Id == id);
            return View(rev);
        }
}
```

Then, when I access  /restaurant/index, I obviously can see a list of all restaurants because in Index.cshtml I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<DCForum.Models.RestaurantModel>

    @foreach (var i in Model)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(myitem => i.Name) 
        @Html.DisplayFor(myitem => i.Location)
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = i.Id })

    }
```

And when I click on the Edit link, this view is triggered (Edit.cshtml):

```
@model DCForum.Models.RestaurantModel
            @using(Html.BeginForm()) { 
                 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                <fieldset>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)

                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                </fieldset>
            }
```

I am clicking the save button but the value I enter for Name is not recorded when I return to Index. What am I missing here? It's pretty obvious I am missing something. How can I make the update happen?

PS. Would it be more recommendable to do this in a more straightforward manner, maybe without using the helpers and just associate an update method with the save button? (just talk).

Comment: Does hitting "Save" on your edit page actually do anything?  I don't see any code to actually update anything.

Comment: @Becuzz Doesn't need to. OP has wrapped logic in "BeginForm", probably needs to pass in the parameters and/or "Id" to locate the controller/method. I generally don't use BeginForm... but rather guessing. - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: You don't have an `ActionMethod` to receive the `POST` data.  It should look something like `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Edit(RestaurantModel restaurant)`

Comment: @TezWingfield I know they used BeginForm, so it should go back to the Edit method.  However, there isn't one set up to take the POST data and do anything with it.  Which means it's probably just executing the Edit method which looks more like a GET.  If the server doesn't do anything with the POST and executes a GET-like method, it isn't surprising nothing gets updated.

Comment: @Becuzz completely agree...(+1)

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to add the HttpPost method. Thank you all very much for pointing this out.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {

            var review = rr.Single(r => r.Id == id);
            if (TryUpdateModel(review))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(review);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an `ActionResult` for the `HttpGet` action, but nothing to receive the `HttpPost` action.  Create a new `ActionResult` with the `HttpPostAttribute` on it, and an argument that matches the model, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Restaurant restaurant)
{
    //Save restaurant here

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The `ModelBinder` will pick this up, and populate `restaurant` for you from the form that was submitted.